# 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute '__getitem__' Error in Python Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

This is my code. I get this error everytime I press login:

**'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute '__getitem__'**

This is my login tab:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error= None
    if request.method == "POST":
        with sql.connect("database.db") as con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            try:
                data = cur.execute("SELECT name FROM users WHERE name= ?",(request.form['username'],) )
                data.fetchone()

                if sha256_crypt.verify(request.form['password'], data[0]):
                    session['logged_in'] == True
                    session['username'] = request.form('username')
                    flash('Successfully logged in')
                    return redirect(url_for(hello_world))
                else:
                    error = "Invalid Password or User. Try again."

            except Exception as e:
                flash(e)
                return render_template('login.html',error=error)
        con.close()
        gc.collect()
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: read the doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__getitem__` refers to square bracket access, in this case `data[0]`. The error tells you that you can't use cursors like that. Replace `data[0]` with the value returned from `data.fetchone()`.

Comment: x = data.fetchone()

                if sha256_crypt.verify(request.form['password'], x):

Comment: Like that? I'm getting another error now which says: 
hash must be unicode or bytes, not sqlite3.Cursor

Comment: Your code seems right but your error is surprising. What if you `print(x)`? It should be a tuple or `None`.

Comment: I think my bug is in my sql statement...

data = cur.execute("SELECT name FROM users WHERE name= '?'" (request.form['username'],) )

Comment: You definitely need to `SELECT` the password hash, not `name`, but that doesn't explain your error message.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me, If I Select my password hash.
Like that?

data = cur.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE password= %s" % (sha256_crypt.encrypt((str(request.form['password']))))

Comment: No, don't change anything except the `SELECT` part. You're looking up the password based on the name. Your current statements `SELECT x WHERE x = ?` are pointless, they just give you back what you already know.

Comment: ata = cur.execute("SELECT name FROM users WHERE password= %s" % (request.form['password']))
                data = data.fetchone()

                if sha256_crypt.verify(request.form['password'], data):

Comment: I don't get it >:<

Comment: No that will look up the username based on the entered password. That doesn't make sense. The user has told you the username and what they think the correct password is, so you should look up the correct password based on that username. `SELECT password FROM users WHERE name = ?`. I don't know how `admin` got there.

Comment: I put admin and admin in the 'username' and 'password' input field, because in my Database there's an user with 'admin' - 'admin'

Comment: My QUERY: ` data = cur.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE name= ?", (request.form['username']))`

and the Error: `Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied.`

Comment: `(x)` is just `x`. In your code it got `"admin"` so it split that into 5 letters because it expects an iterable. To make a tuple with one element, write `(x,)`.

Comment: `tuple index out of range`

Comment: You should really tell me more. In any case the problem is probably that `data.fetchone()` actually returns a tuple (in this case with one element) so you should use `[0]` on that to get out the password.

Comment: Code: `data = cur.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE name= ?", (request.form['username']))

                data = cur.fetchone()[0]

                if sha256_crypt.verify(request.form['password'], data):`

Error I get: `Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied.`

Comment: Yes, what I was saying before is that you need to write `(request.form['username'],)`. Note the comma.

Comment: Error now: `not a valid sha256_crypt hash`
We getting there! Haha :)

Comment: If you can't solve it, make a new question with a [mcve], so no flask app (and probably no DB either).

Comment: Okay. Atleast I know there's something wrong with my encryption.