# sqlite3 ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack on python3

Tags: python, list, sqlite

I have this method in a class, to query multiple values, but when I execute it, brings up the following error
    ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack, some help to figure out the problem.

thanks in advance

```
def _query_values_by_symbol(self, table, symbol, data):
    conn = None
    values = []
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect( self.file_path )
        c = conn.cursor()
        if table == 'ANALYSIS':
            data_row = c.execute("SELECT * FROM ANALYSIS WHERE Symbol=?", (symbol,))
            for _query in data:
                values.append(data_row[_query])
        else:
            pass

    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print ("Database error in _query_values_by_symbol: %s" % e)
    except Exception as e:
        print ("Exception in _query_values_by_symbol: %s" % e)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()
    return values


vs, vss, vsss = db._query_values_by_symbol( 'ANALYSIS', 'USD', [4,5,6])

print (vs, vss, vss)
```

Comment: Check the length of `values`. It looks like it's length is not equal to 3 and hence `vs, vss, vsss` are not enough to unpack

Comment: it seems that the method is not appending any values... values = []

Comment: Good. Now you need to debug whats wrong with append

Comment: this is the problem: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with `sqlite`. Wait for others to chip in

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40207938/sqlite3-cursor-object-has-no-attribute-getitem-error-in-python-flask)

Answer (score 0):

solution was this:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM ANALYSIS WHERE Symbol=?", (symbol,))
                data_row = c.fetchone()
                for _query in data:
                    values.append(data_row[_query])
```